# Display automatically an Integer value from Edit Text (entered by the user) to Text View without any actions?

Tags: java, android

I want to complete a project in which the user writes different characters like A, D, C in an edit text box and then automatically the values of those characters are collected (Addition in each other) in another text box.
For example if user pressed A then its value to textbox 10 and then user pressed B, its value 20 to textbox with A+B value. I am using the given code but not getting success.

`your text`
  saif1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit)
{
String text  = mEdit.toString();

```
            if (text.equals("A")) {

                    charactervalue.setText("10");
                    
                String n1 = charactervalue.getText().toString();
                int n11 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                String n2 = result.getText().toString();
                int n22 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
                finaltotal.setText(String.valueOf(n11 + n22));

            }else if(text.equals("B")) {

                charactervalue.setText("20");

            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code

```
binding.saif1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) {
        String text = mEdit.toString();
        int temp = 0;

        for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch == 'A') {
                temp += 10;
            } else if (ch == 'B') {
                temp += 20;
            }
        }

        binding.textView.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
    }
});
```

You can add more condition by duplicating `else if` case.. e.g.

```
else if (ch == 'C') {
    temp += 30;
}
```